# Logical Error; terminal is showing both possible answers

Tags: java, logic

I'm new to programming and logical errors; I've looked for a similar problem but nothing quite matches mine. We have an assignment to make a program where the user enters their first and last name--if the names are the same, it returns "your first and last name are the same" and if the names are different, it returns "your first and last name are different".

My problem is that it keeps returning BOTH answers no matter what names are typed in. If you run it and try your own name in it, you'll see what I mean.

Here's my code (we have to use scanner):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameAssignment
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String firstName;
    System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
    firstName = stdIn.nextLine();
    String lastName;
    System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
    lastName = stdIn.nextLine();    
    if (firstName == lastName); 
         System.out.println("Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName + "," + " " + "your first name and last name are the same.");
    if (firstName != lastName);
        System.out.println("Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName + "," + " " + "your first name and last name are different.");


} // end main
} // end class NameAssignment
```

UPDATE

I tried correcting it with the suggestions below, and here's what it looks like now:

```html
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameAssignment
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);
 String firstName;
 System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
 firstName = stdIn.nextLine();
 String lastName;
 System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
 lastName = stdIn.nextLine(); 
 if (firstName.equals(lastName)) 
   System.out.println("Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName + "," + " " + "your first name and last name are the same.");
 else (!firstName.equals(lastName)
  System.out.println("Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName + "," + " " + "your first name and last name are different.");
 

} // end main
} // end class NameAssignment
```

I ran it in terminal, and it gave me this:

```html
NameAssignment.java:16: error: ')' expected
 else (!firstName.equals(lastName)
                                  ^
NameAssignment.java:16: error: not a statement
 else (!firstName.equals(lastName)
      ^
NameAssignment.java:17: error: illegal start of expression
  System.out.println("Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName + "," + " " + "your first name and last name are different.");
        ^
NameAssignment.java:17: error: ';' expected
  System.out.println("Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName + "," + " " + "your first name and last name are different.");
            ^
4 errors
```

Comment: [Take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Look at those 'if' statements. What do those trailing semicolons do?

Comment: Don't see any JavaScript here.

Comment: I hope you're using a decent IDE, it should show you where your syntax error is. If you want to use else branch with condition, use `else if` instead of `else`. Also you're missing a closing `)`. That's why it's better to use `{` and `}` around if-else or loop bodies even if they have only one line -- you would get a better error message.

Answer (score 0):

To compare 2 `Strings` in java, you must use `if (firstName.equals(lastName))` because in `Java` `==` operator checks 2 `String` objects and `.equals()` checks `String` values.

Also, you must remove the semicolon `;` after the `if` statement or else that wont execute your `if` condition.

Comment: That may be *a* problem, but it is not *the* problem. ;-)

Comment: Save your answer for the OP's *next* question :-D

Comment: I'm in a hurry so I just Edited it.

Comment: The trailing semi is not a syntax error. If you're going to give the answer, tell the OP *why* it's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `else` clause is wrong. Just replace your `else` clause with the following `else` clause:

```
else
    System.out.println("Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName + "," + " " + "your first name and last name are different.");
```

That's it. `else` doesn't need a condition. That's why `else (!firstName.equals(lastName))` is wrong.

Comment: This actually was the problem! Thank you for your help! I had to move some semicolons around to make it work, but it finally worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you were missing the ) which i added and removed  the "," + " " because it was un-efficient and it should just be included in the same string which i fixed. Just replace your code with that and it should work

```
    if (firstName.equals(lastName)){ 
                 System.out.println("Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName + ", your first name and last name are the same.");
            }
else (!firstName.equals(lastName)){
                System.out.println("Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName + ", your first name and last name are different.");
    }
```